# Backbone proper way to validate a model value to a dom selected value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Relatively new to backbone so I'm looking for the proper way to validate two values.
Both are simple timestamps to represent an end date.

The first value is from the model.

```
model.get('timestampEnd')
```

The second is an a timestamp that is created from the html (aka a jquery datepicker).

The validation isn't on a `model.set` its when the `change:date` event is fired from the datepicker.  I need to update an element in the view dynamically.

Something like the following (currently in the `view`).

```
@.on `change:date`, @checkDate

checkDate: (newTimestamp) =>
 if @model.get('timestampEnd') > newTimestamp
   @$('.dateMessage').show() #Display a message to the user
 else
   @$('.dateMessage).hide() #A valid change so no message to that user
```

This solution works, but I'm wondering if there is a more backbone proper way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can control it at the level model
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

If you're not acting at the level saving part I think what you are doing is fine. =)

Comment: The value isn't being `set` or saved on a commit call.  It just needs to check its current value vs what the user just entered (and not saved).  Would validate still be a valid option in this use case

Comment: Not really, if you just want to check input value against a model I think your method is perfectly fine. Just you know there is a way to check at the model saving but it's another story right :)